# collections.sort compare selectItem

Tags: sorting, collections, compare

i have a Problem and i hope you can help me,
i have a list of SelectItem to ordern

the inital order is: 
geschieden
ledig
unbekannt
verheiratet
verwitwet

and i will the list like: 
 ledig
verheiratet
geschieden
verwitwet
unbekannt

i have the method implementiert but i don t have the right order:

public List getFamilienstandSelectItems()
    {
         List  getFamilienstandSelectItems  =TK_Familienstand_DS_Values.getInstance().getSelectItems();

```
      Collections.sort(getFamilienstandSelectItems , new Comparator<SelectItem>()
            {
                                    public int compare(SelectItem s1, SelectItem s2)
                {

                    if (s1.getLabel()=="ledig")
                    {
                      return 0;}
                    else if (s1.getLabel()=="verheiratet" )
                    { return 0;}
                         else if (s2.getLabel()=="geschieden" )
                         { return 1;}              
                    else if (s2.getLabel()=="unbekannt" )
                         { return -1;}
                         else if (s2.getLabel()=="verwitwet " )
                         { return 0;}

              else return 1;


                     }  });


     return getFamilienstandSelectItems;
    }
```

and the result of this method: 
ledig
verheiratet
geschieden
unbekannt
verwitwet

something is missing??

thank you

Answer (score 0):

The compare method should tell us, of the two items that I'm comparing right now, which one should come first? Negative numbers means that the second item should come first, 0 means that they are equal and positive numbers means that the first item should come first.

So give each item type a number and create a function

```
public int getPriority(SelectItem item) {
    // Give higher values to the items that should come first
}
```

and then do something like this in your compare method

```
public int compare(SelectItem s1, SelectItem s2) {
    return Integer.compare(getPriority(s1),getPriority(s2));
}
```